# Simple javascript problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition

I have one simple problem i guess that i can't solve

Here is the complete code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.3/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#content{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: -300px;
}
#content1{
    width:300px;
    background-color:#33FF00;
    height:300px;
    z-index:100;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
}
#content2{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#000099;
    z-index:100;
    position: relative;
    top: -400px;
}



-->
</style>


</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
function example_animate(px) {
    $('#content2').animate({
        'marginTop' : px
    });
}
</script>
<script language="javascript">
function example_animate2(px) {
    $('#content1').animate({
        'marginLeft' : px

    });


}
</script>


    <p>

       <input type="button" value="Move Up" onClick="example_animate('-=200px')" />
      <input type="button" value="Move Left" onclick="example_animate2('-=300px')" />

    </p>
    <div id="content1"></div>


    <div id="content">

</div>


<div id="content2"></div>




</body>
</html>
```

Now, few things in which I need help and don't understand how can they be done.
First of all, **how can I make that both animations occur only once?**

Secondly, **how can the green box always appear over the blue one?**

Then, **how can I make buttons disappear after being clicked?**.
So when I for example click "Move Up", I need that button to disappear.

And lastly, **when "Move Left" is triggerd, I need that "Move Up" button disappears also, just like the "Move Left"**, while on the other hand, "Move Left" won't disappear when "Move Up" is clicked ("Move Up" just will)

Is this simple,and could it be done? Please help!

Comment: You might want to split this up into individual questions. You are asking a lot in a single post.

Comment: Well there are four things I want to achieve, one without another is useless for me. But if You can help in one of them,it would be great!!

Comment: Looks like this is on tract to get closed before I get a chance. The issue is that the community tries to make the questions re-usable for other people who have a similar issue. By combining all of these and stating them so explicitly in terms of your exact situation you are limiting the usefulness of the answers to your specific case. Also, the way it is worded kind of comes off as a "do this for me" instead of a question, which isn't often received well.

Comment: Well obviously I can't do it on my own and I need help :) I will rephrase it somehow,but do I need to ask multiple questions in multiple threads?

Comment: My Advice: Make an attempt on your own and ask specific questions where you get stuck instead of posting a specification and asking for someone to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

**>>how can I make buttons disappear after being clicked**
If you set ID to buttons, it could be done like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button1").click(function () {
$(this).hide();
}); 
});
```

By using $(element).click(...) you add event listener to specific element, but it can be done only after dom is ready. Read about js and events to understand what i'm talking about.

**>>when "Move Left" is triggerd, I want that "Move Up" button disappears also, just like the "Move Left"**
add click handler for moveLeft where moveUp disappears just like in example above
*Edit: "this" refers to the clicked element. use moveUp id in the moveLeft click handler to make it disappear.*
**>>I need that the green box always appears over the blue one**
set z-index style for your boxes
**>>I want that both animations can occur only once**
You could set up some animationComplete variable that shows whether animation was complete or not.

Comment: Thank You! I've made green box appear over everything else,now I will try everything else You have written